# RSpec2 error codes testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have an issue with testing error codes. If a record is not found, it raises exception ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. The thing is, I wanna check if 404 is returned. If I go ahead and just check :

```
 response.status.should == 404
```

Then this will make the test case fail as RecordNotFound exception is thrown and not caught. If I go ahead and say

```
expect {<call controller action>}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

and then check for the status code, then it will fail again, as this catches the exception and the response code is 200.

How  should I test if 404 is returned in this kind of case ?

Comment: Having the exact same issue! I need to skip/bypass at least one exception to see what has been returned (e.g. 404, 400, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want checking the exceptions in other examples you can set the following options in your `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

Comment: I am checking for exceptions in few other cases, is there a way of suppressing fail even if an exception is thrown on per test case basis ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the specifics well enough to know if this will help you, but check out `bypass_rescue` as described at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/bypass-rescue.